# Is it possible to read a Parquet dataset partitioned by hand using Dask with the Fastparquet reader?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, dask, parquet, fastparquet

I created a Parquet dataset partitioned as follows:

```
2019-taxi-trips/
    - month=1/
        - data.parquet
    - month=2/
        - data.parquet
    ...
    - month=12/
        - data.parquet
```

This organization follows the [Parquet dataset partitioning convention](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery) used by Hive Metastore. This partitioning scheme was generated by hand, so there is no `_metadata` file anywhere in the directory tree.

I would like to now read this dataset into Dask.

With data located on local disk, the following code works:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
dd.read_parquet(
    "/Users/alekseybilogur/Desktop/2019-taxi-trips/*/data.parquet",
    engine="fastparquet"
)
```

I copied these files to an S3 bucket (via `s3 sync`; partition folders are top level keys in the bucket, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwymZ.jpg)), and attempted to read them off of cloud storage using the same basic function:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd; dd.read_parquet(
    "s3://2019-nyc-taxi-trips/*/data.parquet",
    storage_options={
        "key": "...",
        "secret": "..."
    },
    engine="fastparquet")
```

This raises `IndexError: list index out of range`. [Full stack trace here](https://gist.github.com/ResidentMario/f6cd4e53c369b9d0de5a8b1eb6087067).

Is not is currently possible to read in such a dataset directly from AWS S3?

Comment: This sounds like a bug, you should post on the dask tracker

Comment: Filed as https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/6713.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently a bug in `fastparquet` that is preventing this code from working. See [Dask GH#6713](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/6713) for details.

In the meantime, until this bug is resolved, one easy solution to this issue is to use the `pyarrow` backend instead.

```py
dd.read_parquet(
    "s3://2019-nyc-taxi-trips/*/data.parquet",
    storage_options={
        "key": "...",
        "secret": "..."
    },
    engine="pyarrow"
)
```